# S3 return Access denied when querystring having 'location' key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

#### Problem

- I am trying to access index.html in my s3 bucket.
- Everything is okay when I am accessing the file having other querystrings.
- However, It throws errors "Access denied" when querystring key "location" is included.

#### Expected Result

- I expected s3 did not return "Access denied".

#### How to reproduce

- The URL below return status "ok"

  - https://stackoverflow-question.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/index.html
- The URL below throw errors "Access denied"

  - https://stackoverflow-question.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/index.html?location=

Comment: That is apparently an important keyword for S3. Have you tried using [S3 static website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html) to access the content instead?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I thought like so too. I didn't try to use static website hosting. Even if it is an important keyword for s3. I can't believe that this is intended.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein When using static website hosting, it works as expected.

Comment: Does that solve your problem then?

Comment: I think so. But, I still want to know what it occurs. Thanks for your comment! @JohnRotenstein